# Wrong template location after overwrite

Tags: magento2, layout, template, widgets

I have overwritten the `_beforeToHtml()` method in the class `Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList`. After doing this, I received the following error:

```
Invalid template file: 'product/widget/content/grid.phtml' in module: 'My_Module'
```

When I move the `product/widget/content/grid.phtml` template from my theme to my module, the error message dissapears. When I add the `Magento_CatalogWidget::` prefix to the template in widgets.xml, the error doesn't go away.

Comment: share the code what you have try.

Comment: What is the full path of your `product/widget/content/grid.phtml` ?

Comment: @PRINCE `My/Theme/Magento/Catalog/templates/product/widget/content/grid.phtml`, but now I am forced to place it in `My/Module/view/frontend/templates/product/widget/content/grid.phtml`

Comment: So your need is to place it in module or theme ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to rewrite that template in your **module**, you have to do it via xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance dc" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <referenceBlock name="{block.name}">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_CatalogWidget::product/widget/content/grid.phtml</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
</page>
```